# Derivatives of Matrices and Vectors

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I am currently studying deep learning and a lot of the calculus involving differentiating products or sums of ill defined operations on matrices and vectors is very confusing.

For instance, take this example:

$X$ is an $N \times D$ matrix, and let $b$ be a $D$ dimensional row.
Now, a sum such as $X + b$ itself isn't generally defined, but fine, we add the appropriate entries of $b$ with elements of columns of $X$ for each row.

So, let $A = X + b$ as defined above. Let $dX$ also be an $N \times D$ sized matrix.

I want to find the product $$\frac{dA}{db} . dX$$ of size $D \times 1$
or the other way, if the order isn't correct.

So, I want to ask, is there some reference or book I can read to make sense of such sums and products rather than mostly relying on intuition?

Comment: Why dont you write $A$ as $A = N + \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} D$? Then you can calculate with as usual with matrices.

Comment: That's what I did for addition. But what about dividing by a $D$ dimensional vector? How should I take the derivative then?

Comment: Where are you *dividing* by a vector?

Comment: I should've been more concrete from the start. My apologies. I have a $N \times D$ sized matrix, and I want to normalize it, where mean and std dev. are calculated separately for each column.

Comment: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let $1\in {\mathbb R}^{N},\,$ be a vector of ones of length $N$.

Then you can express $A$ and its differential as 
$$\eqalign{
 A &= X + 1\,b^T \cr
dA &= dX + 1\,db^T \cr
}$$
Since $\,\frac{\partial b^T}{\partial b}=I,\,$ (the identity matrix) the gradient of $A$ wrt $b$ is the third-order tensor
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial A}{\partial b} &= 1\,I \cr
}$$ 
and the product of this tensor with $X$ is another third-order tensor
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial A}{\partial b}\,dX &= 1\,dX \cr
}$$